# Eclipse has randommly stopped loading

Tags: java, eclipse, exception, crash, access-violation

So, I've gone to open eclipse like I normally do (clicking the icon in my taskbar) after about a month of not working, and... nothing. There is a bit of hard drive activity but no processes actually stay alive, if they start at all.

After investigating further I found that the splash screen would come up if I ran the executable as Administrator (I'm running Windows 7 by the way), but before the progress bar appeared it crashed generating a file named `hs_err_pid2620.txt` containing the following:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00000000779b0895, pid=2620, tid=996
#
# JRE version: 7.0_03-b05
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (22.1-b02 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [ntdll.dll+0x50895]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x0000000002fef000):  JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_Java, id=996, stack(0x0000000000030000,0x0000000000130000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0xffffffffffffffff

Registers:
RAX=0x000000000012dc68, RBX=0x0000000000000002, RCX=0x000000000012dd38, RDX=0x000000000012dca8
RSP=0x000000000012dc58, RBP=0x000007fee9f266e0, RSI=0x0000000000000020, RDI=0x0000000000000000
R8 =0x0000000000125000, R9 =0x0000000000000003, R10=0x0000000000000000, R11=0x0000000000003b95
R12=0x0000000000000000, R13=0x0000000000000050, R14=0x0000000000000003, R15=0x0000000002fef000
RIP=0x00000000779b0895, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010202

Top of Stack: (sp=0x000000000012dc58)
0x000000000012dc58:   0000000000000202 000000007796b239
0x000000000012dc68:   000007fffffde000 0000000000000051
0x000000000012dc78:   00000000081e5888 000000000012de00
0x000000000012dc88:   0000000000000000 000000000012de70
0x000000000012dc98:   000000006b06e908 000000000000000a
0x000000000012dca8:   0000000000130000 0000000000125000
0x000000000012dcb8:   0000000007a31630 000000000012e4d0
0x000000000012dcc8:   000000000302743a 00000000030273d0
0x000000000012dcd8:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x000000000012dce8:   000000000012e4d0 000000000012e5b0
0x000000000012dcf8:   0000000002ff6038 000000006b1815ab
0x000000000012dd08:   0000000000000000 000000000012e610
0x000000000012dd18:   000056db5fdc4851 000000000012e500
0x000000000012dd28:   0000000002feca70 000000006b181aab
0x000000000012dd38:   000000000012de98 00000000f83af1d8
0x000000000012dd48:   000000000012e500 00000000d825d98b 

Instructions: (pc=0x00000000779b0895)
0x00000000779b0875:   d0 00 00 00 4c 89 a1 d8 00 00 00 4c 89 a9 e0 00
0x00000000779b0885:   00 00 4c 89 b1 e8 00 00 00 4c 89 b9 f0 00 00 00
0x00000000779b0895:   0f ae 81 00 01 00 00 0f 29 81 a0 01 00 00 0f 29
0x00000000779b08a5:   89 b0 01 00 00 0f 29 91 c0 01 00 00 0f 29 99 d0 


Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x000000000012dc68 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0000000002fef000
RBX=0x0000000000000002 is an unknown value
RCX=0x000000000012dd38 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0000000002fef000
RDX=0x000000000012dca8 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0000000002fef000
RSP=0x000000000012dc58 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0000000002fef000
RBP=0x000007fee9f266e0 is an unknown value
RSI=0x0000000000000020 is an unknown value
RDI=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R8 =0x0000000000125000 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0000000002fef000
R9 =0x0000000000000003 is an unknown value
R10=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R11=0x0000000000003b95 is an unknown value
R12=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R13=0x0000000000000050 is an unknown value
R14=0x0000000000000003 is an unknown value
R15=0x0000000002fef000 is a thread


Stack: [0x0000000000030000,0x0000000000130000],  sp=0x000000000012dc58,  free space=1015k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [ntdll.dll+0x50895]  RtlCaptureContext+0x85

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
v  blob 0x00000000030274ff
j  java.util.jar.Attributes.putValue(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;+13
j  java.util.jar.Attributes.read(Ljava/util/jar/Manifest$FastInputStream;[B)V+301
j  java.util.jar.Manifest.read(Ljava/io/InputStream;)V+291
j  sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.processImpl(Ljava/util/Hashtable;Ljava/util/List;)V+20
j  sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.process(Ljava/util/Hashtable;Ljava/util/List;)V+9
j  java.util.jar.JarVerifier.processEntry(Lsun/security/util/ManifestEntryVerifier;)V+387
j  java.util.jar.JarVerifier.update(I[BIILsun/security/util/ManifestEntryVerifier;)V+39
j  java.util.jar.JarFile.initializeVerifier()V+107
j  java.util.jar.JarFile.getInputStream(Ljava/util/zip/ZipEntry;)Ljava/io/InputStream;+25
j  sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader$2.getInputStream()Ljava/io/InputStream;+11
j  sun.misc.Resource.cachedInputStream()Ljava/io/InputStream;+9
j  sun.misc.Resource.getByteBuffer()Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;+1
j  java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Ljava/lang/String;Lsun/misc/Resource;)Ljava/lang/Class;+132
j  java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Ljava/net/URLClassLoader;Ljava/lang/String;Lsun/misc/Resource;)Ljava/lang/Class;+3
j  java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run()Ljava/lang/Class;+43
j  java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run()Ljava/lang/Object;+1
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
j  java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Ljava/security/PrivilegedExceptionAction;Ljava/security/AccessControlContext;)Ljava/lang/Object;+0
j  java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Class;+13
j  java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Ljava/lang/String;Z)Ljava/lang/Class;+70
j  java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Class;+3
j  org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework([Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/net/URL;)V+101
j  org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun([Ljava/lang/String;)V+126
j  org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run([Ljava/lang/String;)I+4
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x00000000068c2000 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2096, stack(0x0000000007440000,0x0000000007540000)]
  0x00000000068b8800 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3160, stack(0x0000000007340000,0x0000000007440000)]
  0x00000000068b2800 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2100, stack(0x0000000007240000,0x0000000007340000)]
  0x00000000068b2000 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2136, stack(0x0000000007140000,0x0000000007240000)]
  0x00000000068a6800 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2144, stack(0x0000000007040000,0x0000000007140000)]
  0x00000000067c9000 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2856, stack(0x0000000006f40000,0x0000000007040000)]
  0x00000000067bc000 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2740, stack(0x0000000006e40000,0x0000000006f40000)]
=>0x0000000002fef000 JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_Java, id=996, stack(0x0000000000030000,0x0000000000130000)]

Other Threads:
  0x00000000067ae800 VMThread [stack: 0x0000000006d40000,0x0000000006e40000] [id=3400]
  0x00000000068d2800 WatcherThread [stack: 0x0000000007540000,0x0000000007640000] [id=2624]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap
 PSYoungGen      total 11968K, used 3878K [0x00000000f8000000, 0x00000000f8d50000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 10304K, 37% used [0x00000000f8000000,0x00000000f83c99e0,0x00000000f8a10000)
  from space 1664K, 0% used [0x00000000f8bb0000,0x00000000f8bb0000,0x00000000f8d50000)
  to   space 1664K, 0% used [0x00000000f8a10000,0x00000000f8a10000,0x00000000f8bb0000)
 PSOldGen        total 27328K, used 0K [0x00000000e8000000, 0x00000000e9ab0000, 0x00000000f8000000)
  object space 27328K, 0% used [0x00000000e8000000,0x00000000e8000000,0x00000000e9ab0000)
 PSPermGen       total 21248K, used 4738K [0x00000000d8000000, 0x00000000d94c0000, 0x00000000e8000000)
  object space 21248K, 22% used [0x00000000d8000000,0x00000000d84a0be0,0x00000000d94c0000)

Code Cache  [0x0000000002ff0000, 0x0000000003260000, 0x0000000005ff0000)
 total_blobs=245 nmethods=26 adapters=172 free_code_cache=48707Kb largest_free_block=49843712

Dynamic libraries:
0x0000000000400000 - 0x000000000044f000     C:\Users\Andy\Desktop\eclipse-java-juno-win32-x86_64\eclipse\eclipse.exe
0x0000000077960000 - 0x0000000077b09000     C:\windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
0x0000000077840000 - 0x000000007795f000     C:\windows\system32\kernel32.dll
0x000007fefded0000 - 0x000007fefdf3c000     C:\windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
0x00000000775e0000 - 0x00000000776da000     C:\windows\system32\USER32.dll
0x000007fefea70000 - 0x000007fefead7000     C:\windows\system32\GDI32.dll
0x000007fefe220000 - 0x000007fefe22e000     C:\windows\system32\LPK.dll
0x000007fefe460000 - 0x000007fefe529000     C:\windows\system32\USP10.dll
0x000007feffbd0000 - 0x000007feffc6f000     C:\windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
0x000007fefc620000 - 0x000007fefc814000     C:\windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.7601.17514_none_fa396087175ac9ac\COMCTL32.dll
0x000007fefe340000 - 0x000007fefe3b1000     C:\windows\system32\SHLWAPI.dll
0x000007fefdc90000 - 0x000007fefdce7000     C:\windows\system32\apphelp.dll
0x000007fee9f80000 - 0x000007fee9fda000     C:\windows\AppPatch\AppPatch64\AcLayers.DLL
0x000007fefb9c0000 - 0x000007fefba31000     C:\windows\system32\WINSPOOL.DRV
0x000007fef9090000 - 0x000007fef90a8000     C:\windows\system32\MPR.dll
0x000007fefe6b0000 - 0x000007fefe7dd000     C:\windows\system32\RPCRT4.dll
0x000007fee9b10000 - 0x000007fee9f77000     C:\windows\AppPatch\AppPatch64\AcXtrnal.DLL
0x000007fee9fe0000 - 0x000007feea031000     C:\windows\AppPatch\AppPatch64\AcGenral.DLL
0x000007fefdc60000 - 0x000007fefdc85000     C:\windows\system32\SspiCli.dll
0x000007fefe7e0000 - 0x000007fefe9e3000     C:\windows\system32\ole32.dll
0x000007fefede0000 - 0x000007feffb68000     C:\windows\system32\SHELL32.dll
0x00000000726d0000 - 0x00000000726d3000     C:\windows\system32\sfc.dll
0x000007fef7af0000 - 0x000007fef7b00000     C:\windows\system32\sfc_os.DLL
0x000007fefd0c0000 - 0x000007fefd0de000     C:\windows\system32\USERENV.dll
0x000007fefddc0000 - 0x000007fefddcf000     C:\windows\system32\profapi.dll
0x000007fefbd90000 - 0x000007fefbda8000     C:\windows\system32\dwmapi.dll
0x000007fefeb00000 - 0x000007fefebdb000     C:\windows\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
0x000007fefeae0000 - 0x000007fefeaff000     C:\windows\SYSTEM32\sechost.dll
0x000007fefe1e0000 - 0x000007fefe20e000     C:\windows\system32\IMM32.DLL
0x000007fefe230000 - 0x000007fefe339000     C:\windows\system32\MSCTF.dll
0x00000000222f0000 - 0x00000000223f5000     C:\Program Files\CheckPoint\ZAForceField\Plugins\ISWSHEX.dll
0x0000000073c20000 - 0x0000000073ce9000     C:\windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.vc80.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.6195_none_88e41e092fab0294\MSVCR80.dll
0x000007fefde70000 - 0x000007fefdeaa000     C:\windows\system32\WINTRUST.dll
0x000007fefdf40000 - 0x000007fefe0aa000     C:\windows\system32\CRYPT32.dll
0x000007fefde60000 - 0x000007fefde6f000     C:\windows\system32\MSASN1.dll
0x0000000073b10000 - 0x0000000073c19000     C:\windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.vc80.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.6195_none_88e41e092fab0294\MSVCP80.dll
0x000007fefc5a0000 - 0x000007fefc5cd000     C:\windows\system32\ntmarta.dll
0x000007feffb70000 - 0x000007feffbc2000     C:\windows\system32\WLDAP32.dll
0x0000000072000000 - 0x0000000072012000     C:\Users\Andy\Desktop\eclipse-java-juno-win32-x86_64\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20120522-1813\eclipse_1503.dll
0x000007fefcd60000 - 0x000007fefcd6c000     C:\windows\system32\VERSION.dll
0x000007fefc380000 - 0x000007fefc3d6000     C:\windows\system32\uxtheme.dll
0x000007fefdcf0000 - 0x000007fefdcff000     C:\windows\system32\CRYPTBASE.dll
0x000007fefe3c0000 - 0x000007fefe459000     C:\windows\system32\CLBCatQ.DLL
0x000007fefe530000 - 0x000007fefe607000     C:\windows\system32\OLEAUT32.dll
0x0000000010000000 - 0x000000001000a000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Lenovo\Energy Management\BatteryTestDLL.dll
0x000000006afc0000 - 0x000000006b69a000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll
0x000007fef1390000 - 0x000007fef1399000     C:\windows\system32\WSOCK32.dll
0x000007fefe190000 - 0x000007fefe1dd000     C:\windows\system32\WS2_32.dll
0x000007fefe210000 - 0x000007fefe218000     C:\windows\system32\NSI.dll
0x000007fefaf60000 - 0x000007fefaf9b000     C:\windows\system32\WINMM.dll
0x0000000077b20000 - 0x0000000077b27000     C:\windows\system32\PSAPI.DLL
0x000000006bca0000 - 0x000000006bd71000     C:\windows\system32\MSVCR100.dll
0x0000000071790000 - 0x000000007179f000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\jre\bin\verify.dll
0x000000006bc70000 - 0x000000006bc98000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\jre\bin\java.dll
0x000000006cc60000 - 0x000000006cc75000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\jre\bin\zip.dll
0x000007fefd690000 - 0x000007fefd6a7000     C:\windows\system32\CRYPTSP.dll
0x000007fefd390000 - 0x000007fefd3d7000     C:\windows\system32\rsaenh.dll
0x000000006bc50000 - 0x000000006bc69000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\jre\bin\net.dll
0x000007fefd630000 - 0x000007fefd685000     C:\windows\system32\mswsock.dll
0x000007fefd620000 - 0x000007fefd627000     C:\windows\System32\wship6.dll
0x000007fefb030000 - 0x000007fefb045000     C:\windows\system32\NLAapi.dll
0x000007fef2750000 - 0x000007fef2765000     C:\windows\system32\napinsp.dll
0x000007fef2770000 - 0x000007fef2789000     C:\windows\system32\pnrpnsp.dll
0x000007fefd4b0000 - 0x000007fefd50b000     C:\windows\system32\DNSAPI.dll
0x000007fef2730000 - 0x000007fef273b000     C:\windows\System32\winrnr.dll
0x000007fef2740000 - 0x000007fef2750000     C:\windows\system32\wshbth.dll
0x0000000072220000 - 0x0000000072246000     C:\Program Files\Bonjour\mdnsNSP.dll
0x000007fefa8e0000 - 0x000007fefa907000     C:\windows\system32\Iphlpapi.DLL
0x000007fefa8c0000 - 0x000007fefa8cb000     C:\windows\system32\WINNSI.DLL
0x000007fef4750000 - 0x000007fef477f000     C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live\WLIDNSP.DLL
0x000007fefcfa0000 - 0x000007fefcfa7000     C:\windows\System32\wshtcpip.dll
0x000007fef4a50000 - 0x000007fef4a58000     C:\windows\system32\rasadhlp.dll
0x000007fefa4c0000 - 0x000007fefa513000     C:\windows\System32\fwpuclnt.dll
0x000000006bc30000 - 0x000000006bc41000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\jre\bin\nio.dll

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5 -Dhelp.lucene.tokenizer=standard -Xms40m -Xmx384m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m 
java_command: <unknown>
Launcher Type: generic

Environment Variables:
CLASSPATH=.;
PATH=C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_03/bin/../jre/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_03/bin/../jre/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_03/bin/../jre/lib/amd64;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\bin;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Users\Andy\Desktop\eclipse-java-juno-win32-x86_64\eclipse;
USERNAME=Andy
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 42 Stepping 7, GenuineIntel



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows 7 , 64 bit Build 6000 

CPU:total 4 (2 cores per cpu, 2 threads per core) family 6 model 42 stepping 7, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt, ht

Memory: 4k page, physical 6233968k(4708700k free), swap 12466084k(10719968k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (22.1-b02) for windows-amd64 JRE (1.7.0_03-b05), built on Feb  3 2012 20:43:56 by "java_re" with unknown MS VC++:1600

time: Sat Jun 30 17:13:23 2012
elapsed time: 0 seconds
```

I have tried everything that I can think of to resolve the issue. I've downloaded the latest version of Eclipse, installed the latest version of both Java and the JDK, and even temporarily disabled UAC as per Java's recommendation but none of that has solved the situation.

As far as I can think, I have not modified anything (certainly not to do with Eclipse) since Eclipse was working fine. However I do have a little bit of a suspicion that my hard drive may not be as healthy as it should be; still, I have not seen anything else 
effected. Therefore, any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I had this problem after I installed a bunch of updates to Eclipse 4.23.0. Installing the latest release of Eclipse did not solve the problem. I installed Eclipse 4.24.0 and the problem went away. I have no idea why. Note that I got a Java error code of -1073740771 (0xc000005).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Unfortunately,** Stephen C's suspicion was correct; it was nothing to do with Eclipse at all.

I guessed that the crashes were down to `ntdll.dll` which concerned me a bit because it is located in the Windows directory. After an extended SMART test in a couple of programs produced an 'read failure', I investigated further to find 28 of my sectors were damaged. At this point reality struck and I realised that my HDD was on its last legs, so I ordered an SSD (because I have a disability that means I can be heavy handed, amongst other reasons). And I'm glad I did.

In  some ways, it's a good job I went to use Eclipse when I did. I could literally see the drive failing - I managed to back up most of my files, some were on bad sectors and even Unstoppable Copier couldn't help; but cloning was a pointless and time consuming exercise. Acronis managed to clone the drive, but it obviously didn't get the vital files - Windows wouldn't load and I ended up reinstalling and loosing my recovery partition - but you can't have anything.

Anyway, all you really needed to know is Eclipse is now working and the problem was caused by damaged sectors on my HDD. Very annoying.

Answer (score 3):

Well, a JVM crash is nasty, and suggests something is seriously wrong.  And looking at the stack trace in the dump, it appears that the code is trying to verify the signature on a JAR file that it is trying to open.  I suspect that you've got a corrupted JAR file, and that would tend to confirm your suspicion that this is related to your hard drive being "unhealthy".

Comment: I was dreading hearing that response. Do you think you would have answers differently if I hadn't mentioned my drive. Also, I would have thought updating Eclipse and Java would have replaced any files that may have gotten corrupted that Eclipse needs...? Any further thought?

Comment: It doesn't blow up in an IO operation, though, but while executing a seemingly innocuous line [`return (String)put(new Name(name), value);`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/jar/Attributes.java#168). OP, does it consistently blow up at exactly this spot?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik By the looks it does but that not a technical definition. How do I find out?

Comment: In several consecutive dumps you should see the same stacktrace. BTW this crash happened while loading class `org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter`, therefore while reading MANIFEST.MF in `org.eclipse.core.runtime-XXX.jar`. You can also check manually what's going on in that jar (in the `plugins` directory).

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Sorry for the slow reply. I can't see any difference in the dump files, certainly not from the line `Stack: [0x0000000000030000,0x0000000000130000],  sp=0x000000000012dc58,  free space=1015k` up until the `PROCESS` line. Also, please remember that these dump files have been created by the latest, untouched, version of Eclipse!

Comment: I meant the Java stacktrace, but if this line is the same, so is the Java stacktrace, very probably. As far as untouched, we're trying to eliminate HD-related problems, so it doesn't matter if it wasn't touched in any explicit manner.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I'm still unsure where to find the Java stacktrace but if it's the but underneath the `PROCESS` line, then the `id`s and `stack`s of the Java threads are slightly different. As far as eliminated HDD related problems, not only has the version of Eclipse been untouched but I've only just downloaded it today and as far as I'm concerned, it didn't have time to become corrupt before I tried to run it.

Answer (score 2):

I just want to share my experience-
I was also getting the same error on running runnable jar file on my PC. I was getting stuck and tried whole night and got nothing useful.
Later I tried same jar file on My Laptop and it is working fine no error nothing.

Hence analyzed more on this and found some sectors of my HDD are corrupted.

Comment: It's debatable if this is an answer since it doesn't provide an explenation nor a reasonable solution. Although it might happen that by restarting problems dissapear, in many cases, one can prevent that.